# bit shift in c language

Tags: c, bit-shift

I tried:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    int a=10000;
    unsigned char cp1=0,cp2=0,cp3=0,cp4=0;

    cp1 = (a & 0xff000000) >> 24;
    cp2 = (a & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
    cp3 = (a & 0x0000ff00) >>  8;
    cp4 = (a & 0x000000ff)      ;

    printf("%d %d %d %d\n",cp1,cp2,cp3,cp4);
}
```

My output is:

```
0 0 39 16
```

I found `(39<<8) + 16=10000`.

I could not understand `cp3=(a & 0x0000ff00)>>8; ==39` how it is working?

I know `0xff=255`, I want to know how the (`&`) operation and `0xff` are working together and taking particular bits.

Can you teach me how it is working?

Comment: Using wrong format specifier invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth; **7.21.6 P(9)**: *If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.282) If any argument is
not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
undefined.*

Comment: @haccks: yup, didn't notice these were `unsigned`.

Comment: @haccks: If all values of an `unsigned char` can be represented by a `signed int` (which is usually the case), the arguments will be promoted to `signed int` which matches the conversion specifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
             a  = 0010 0111 0001 0000
        0xff00  = 1111 1111 0000 0000
   (a & 0xff00) = 0010 0111 0000 0000
(a & 0xff00)>>8 = 0000 0000 0010 0111  //shift the bits of above ANDing 8 times to right
0000 0000 0010 0111 = 39 in decimal
```

Comment: okay friend thanks for your help. you said clear cut answer.thanks again :D

Comment: My pleasure. Btw welcome to our community I hope you've read [FAQ], it's important to read this and enjoyed the Q&A on SO. Cheers